# Create trigger to automatically update column with subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

In my application, I have a couple of tables, `lessons` and `votes`. Here's what they look like:

**Lessons**

```
+-------------+---------+----------------------+
| Column      | Type    | Modifiers            |
|-------------+---------+----------------------|
| id          | uuid    |  not null            |
| votes_total | integer |  not null default 0  |
+-------------+---------+----------------------+
```

**Votes**

```
+-------------+---------+-------------+
| Column      | Type    | Modifiers   |
|-------------+---------+-------------|
| positive    | boolean |  not null   |
| user_id     | uuid    |  not null   |
| lesson_id   | uuid    |  not null   |
+-------------+---------+-------------+
```

Whenever a row in `votes` is inserted, updated or deleted, I'd like to update the `votes_total` column of the related lesson using a subquery. Here's what I've tried:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_lesson_votes_total()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
UPDATE lessons
SET votes_total = (
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN positive THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)
  FROM votes
  WHERE lesson_id = NEW.lesson_id
)
WHERE id = NEW.lesson_id;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER votes_change
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON votes
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_lesson_votes_total();
```

However, when I try to run this in a migration, I get the following error:

```
(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error) cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your function must return a trigger. You can't use new in a trigger on delete. You have to create at least 2 triggers calling the same function and use `TG_OP` to know if the function is triggered by insert, update or delete.

Then in a case or if statement you can use new or old to get the id's value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_lesson_votes_total()
returns trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
begin
UPDATE lessons
SET votes_total = (
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN positive THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)
  FROM votes
  WHERE lesson_id = NEW.lesson_id
)
WHERE id = NEW.lesson_id;

return null;
end;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER votes_change_u_i
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON votes
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_lesson_votes_total();

CREATE TRIGGER votes_change_d
AFTER DELETE ON votes
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_lesson_votes_total();
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! The function syntax now seems to be correct, and I'm able to create it independently. However, I'm still getting a `cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement` error when attempting to run the trigger portion of the code.

Comment: Where do you get the error ? In PGAdmin, in code in your software ?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. I was getting this in my migration system because there were multiple statements in the SQL string. There's nothing wrong with the trigger function—it's just the second statement that was causing the error. Thank you for all the help!